# How to get array with number from string

Tags: javascript

Little bit of different format of array.

```
var string = "A,B,C,D";
```

Output should be:

```
drp1: {A:-1,B:-2,C:-3,D:-4}
```

I cannot figure out how to get such format with JavaScipt.

Comment: `drp1` is an _Object_, not an _Array_

Comment: Take a look at `String.split()` at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Answer (score 2):

```
var letters = string.split(',');
var drp1 = {};
for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    drp1[letters[i]] = -1 - i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "A,B,C,D";
var res = {};
string.split(',').forEach(function(e, i) {
  res[e] = - (i + 1);
});
console.log(res);//prints {A: -1, B: -2, C: -3, D: -4}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.map` (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))

```
var obj = {};
'A,B,C,D'.split(',').map(function (v, i) {this[a] = -(i+1);}, obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be to use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to convert your string to an array, then use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to construct the object in the form you want:

```
var string = "A,B,C,D"
var drp1 = string.split(',').reduce(function(o,x,i){
    o[x] = -1 - i; 
    return o; 
}, {});
```

Note that `reduce` was introduced in ECMAScript 5.1, so it may not work in older browsers. If this is a concern, use the polyfill technique described in the linked documentation, or a simple `for`-loop as *Barmar*'s answer shows.